# C# MVC Convert Model into String Array

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, csv

I have a model which I populate from a fairly complex query. The model looks like:

```
public class CSVExportViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string StudentNo { get; set; }
    public string StudentIdNumber { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Parent1IdNumber { get; set; }
    public string Parent1Name { get; set; }
    public string Parent2IdNumber { get; set; }
    public string Parent2Name { get; set; }
    /* etc... */
}
```

I now need to output the model to a CSV file using the code below:

```
List<CSVExportViewModel> data = GetData(dataset);

foreach (CSVExportViewModel item in data)
{
    writer.WriteLine("'" + string.Join("','", item) + "'");
}
```

However, instead of converting the model into an array and outputting the individual items of the model, it just outputs "Models.CSVExportViewModel" to each line of the resulting CSV file.

How can I convert the model into a String array to get this working properly?

Comment: I don't know what `CSVExportViewModel` is, but it definitely not string. So, C# compiler is printing `classname`.

Comment: You're telling it to write the `CSVExportViewModel` to string right? But I bet you haven't written a `ToString` method in that class, so it doesn't know how to output that to string. Thus you just get the class name

Comment: You need to output each property of `CSVExportViewModel`

Comment: You propably need to call `item.Text` or `item.Value` for this to work. Right now you are writing the name of the object containing various information to the file.

Comment: look for the definition of ToString() method on CSVExportViewModel

Comment: So is there no easy way to do this? Do I need to add a ToArray() method to the Model and add each property to the String[]?

Comment: Can please share how CsvExportViewmodel class looks like?

Comment: [Iterate properties of the class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317061/c-sharp-array-of-properties) may be the keyword you need to search for.

Comment: Thanks @MathewJibin. That did the Trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. @MathewJibin pointed me in the right direction. I implemented ToArray() in my model as follows:

```
public class CSVExportViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string StudentNo { get; set; }
    public string StudentIdNumber { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Parent1IdNumber { get; set; }
    public string Parent1Name { get; set; }
    public string Parent2IdNumber { get; set; }
    public string Parent2Name { get; set; }
    /* etc... */
    public String[] ToArray()
    {
        List<string> arr = new List<string>();

        foreach (var prop in typeof(CSVExportViewModel).GetProperties())
        {
            string value = "";
            if (prop.GetValue(this, null) != null)
            {
                value = prop.GetValue(this, null).ToString();
            }

            arr.Add(value);
        }

        return arr.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then just had to modify the code to call item.ToArray();

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

implement ToString() in CSVExportViewModel class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Id + ", " + StudentNo + ", " + StudentIdNumber + ", " + StudentName + ", " +
    Parent1IdNumber + ", " + Parent1Name + ", " + Parent2IdNumber + ", " + Parent2Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array on fly

```
foreach (CSVExportViewModel item in data)
{
    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",",  new object[] {item.prop1, item.prop2, item.prop3 ...}));
}
```