# Insert SP in EF Core

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I am using EF Core as my ORM. Ideally, I would use SaveChanges/ SaveChangesAsync to insert data into my DB, but there is a scenario where my table doesn't have a PK nor I can create it, not even a composite key. So I decided to write a Merge SP and call it using FromSQL.

My question is, is it possible to create a function of my merge SP something that we used to do in EF, that would enable me to pass my class obj into my merge function, instead of passing all the values as parameters.

Any help would be appreciated..Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Usually I create a wrapper for my SPs in the DbContext class I'm using. For example:

```
// Table already created in the DBContext class
public DbQuery<Data> TblData { get; set; }

public void SpInsertData(Data data)
{
    TblData.FromSqlInterpolated("exec [dbo].[sp_InsertData] {data.A}, {data.B}, {data.C}");
}
```

This way I only have to write the list of parameters only once.

---

If you don't even want to write down the property list once, you can use reflection to get the property values. You can write a fuction on your class that gives back every property value in an array (using [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317061/c-sharp-array-of-properties)):

```
class Data
{
    public int A{ get; }
    public string B{ get; }
    public bool C{ get; }

    public string[] GetAllPropertyValues()
    {
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        foreach (var pi in typeof(MyType).GetProperties())
        {
            values.Add(pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
        }

        return values.ToArray();
    }
}
```

With this you can write the previous call to the SP without listing the property values:

```
public DbQuery<Data> TblData { get; set; }

public void SpInsertData(Data data)
{
    TblData.FromSqlRaw("exec [dbo].[sp_InsertData]", data.GetAllPropertyValues());
}
```

However, **I do not suggest you to use this approach**, as it can lead to many silent errors: if even the *order* of the properties change (either in the code or in the SP), you can insert data into the wrong columns, and you will not get an error about it if the types are otherwise correct. It is much safer if you list those properties, you only need to do it once, but it won't result in errors later.

Comment: I am looking for something similar, the only problem is that I have a long list of parameters, so I was looking for a way if this can be achieved without listing down all the parameters. An inbuilt function or something.

Comment: I added another idea to my answer. However, I think your main goal would be to do everything to add a primary key to the table, because that is a fundamental flaw in the design and every solution that tries to go around this problem will only make future errors more likely.

Comment: I am aware that adding PK would have been the best solution, but what I have is a Staging Database so by design it is kept like that and I cant change the ORM now :)